# in R how to replace a text in Variable Y which match with a string (in Variable X) containing a spacific word

Tags: r

How do I replace a string in Variable Y which matches with a string (in Variable X) containing a specific word?

I have job description in variable X. In Variable Y I should assign a short title "with one or two words", the object is to get only 5 titles for 30K rows of descriptions.

A code for the wording: replace in data$Y with "Sport" whenever data$Y containing "Ball" 
Ball could be in uper or lower case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi Feriel, could you include an example data frame, and an example of what you've tried to do so far? In a general sense, the regex function grep and grepl are what you should look into.